# proving that $\frac{d}{dx}\phi_j(x)=\frac{4}{l}\sum_{m=0 \\ (j+m) odd}^{j-1}\frac{3j-2m}{\xi_m}\phi_m(x)+\eta^l_j(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, numerical-methods

Given that $$\frac{d}{dx}T^l_k(x)=\frac{1}{l}\sum_{m=0 \\(k+m)odd}^{k-1}\frac{4k} {\xi_m}T^l_m(x)$$
AND $$\phi_j(x)=x(l-x)T^l_j(x)$$
Where $$
\xi_m =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  2  &  m = 0 \\
  1 & otherwise
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
Prove that $$\frac{d}{dx}\phi_j(x)=\frac{4}{l}\sum_{m=0 \\ (j+m) odd}^{j-1}\frac{3j-2m}{\xi_m}\phi_m(x)+\eta^l_j(x)$$
where $$\eta^l_j(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  l-2x  &j \ \ \ even \\
  -l & j \ \ \  odd
 \end{array}
\right.$$
What i have got so far is $$\frac{d}{dx}\phi_j(x)=(l-2x)T^l_k(x)+\frac{4}{l}\sum_{m=0 \\(j+m) odd}^{j-1}\frac{j}{\xi_m}\phi_m(x)$$
Edited $$T^l_k(x) =\cos(k \cos^{-1}(2x/l -1 ))$$
How to get the required result?

Comment: $T^l_k$ is shifted chebyshev on $x \in [0,l]$

Comment: Sorry it's supposed to be $k$ not $i$.I have edited my post

Comment: In the equation after, "what I have got so far", shouldn't $T_k^l$ be $T_j^l$?  $k$ appears nowhere else in the equation.

Comment: that's right it's $T^l_j$